# gcc does not resolve extern global variables, with or without -c option

Tags: c, gcc, linker, global, extern

So i have this issue : i am declaring some extern global variables in my C program.
If I don't use the -c option for gcc, i get undefined references errors. But with that -c option, the linking is not done, which means that i don't have an executable generated.

So how do I solve this?

Here is my makefile (written thanks to Alex)

```
CC = gcc                      # compiler/linker frontend
INCL = -I$(INCL_DIR)          # includes
DEFS = -D_DEBUG_              # defines
CFLAGS = -g $(INCL) $(DEFS)   # compiler flags
LFLAGS = -lpthread -lm -g     # linker flags

OBJ = approx.o producteur.o sequentialApproximation.o main.o
BIN = calculPi.exe
LINKOBJ  = approx.o producteur.o sequentialApproximation.o main.o
RM = rm -fv

all: $(BIN)

clean:
 ${RM} *\~ \#*\# $(OBJ)

clean_all: clean
 ${RM} $(BIN)

cleanall: clean
 ${RM} $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
 $(CC) $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $^

main.o: main.c
approx.o: approx.c approx.h
producteur.o: producteur.c producteur.h
sequentialApproximation.o : sequentialApproximation.c sequentialApproximation.h

.c.o:
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

And here is the output of make : http://pastebin.com/NzsFetrn

I did declare extern variables in approx.h (extern and global) and i try to call them in approx.c, and there it doesn't work.

Comment: You can remove the LINKOBJ variable, it's redundant. You need to define your variables, simply declaring them extern is not enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution 1

You can't pass `-c` in your linking phase, as that will tell the compiler to skip linking.

Your problem is

```
$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(LINKOBJ) -o "calculPi.exe"
```

with

```
CXX_FLAGS =-g -c -lpthread -lm
```

where `$(CXX)` expands to `gcc -g -c -lpthread -lm ...`

get rid of the `-c` there.

Only pass -c when compiling from source to object modules.

### Solution 2

Re the second problem, you aren't actually defining the variables anywhere. In your `.c` file you need the lines:

```
Coord* production;
int indice_prod;
int indice_cons;
```

(Assuming you really want global variables). This will fix the unresolved external error.
You can't write to them until they've been allocated!

### Notes

Also note that you can specify how to build object files from source in one rule:

```
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

and specify the dependencies without rules:

```
main.o: main.c
approx.o: approx.c approx.h
producteur.o: producteur.c producteur.h
sequentialApproximation.o : sequentialApproximation.c sequentialApproximation.h
```

etc.

### Other notes.

Also, as general rule of thumb, `CXX` should only contain the compiler name, no flags. Those should go in `CXX_FLAGS`. And why are you calling it `CXX` not `CC`? Use `g++` if you want a C++ compiler, or use `CC`. Since you have `.c` files, I'll assume C. So in your case, you should change:

```
CXX_FLAGS =-g -c -lpthread -lm
CXX = gcc $(CXX_FLAGS) $(INCL) $(DEFS)
```

to

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -lpthread -lm $(INCL) $(DEFS)  # also removed -c
```

And you don't need a separate `LINK_CXX`.

### Sample Makefile

So a minimal Makefile should look like:

```
# Makefile
CC = gcc                      # compiler/linker frontend
INCL = -I$(INCL_DIR)          # includes
DEFS = -D_DEBUG_              # defines
CFLAGS = -g $(INCL) $(DEFS)   # compiler flags
LFLAGS = -lpthread -lm -g     # linker flags

OBJ = approx.o producteur.o sequentialApproximation.o main.o
BIN = calculPi.exe

all: $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) -o$@ $^

main.o: main.c
approx.o: approx.c approx.h
producteur.o: producteur.c producteur.h
sequentialApproximation.o : sequentialApproximation.c sequentialApproximation.h

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

# clean and other stuff.
```

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for helping me.

About the how to build object ine one rule thing :
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c
is this correct? It says a separator is missing (again, excuse me as i ma very bad at writing makefiles and i am not good at compiling c code)

Also, when i get rid of the -c in the $(BIN) rule I still have my undefined references back!

Comment: I did not call it CXX, as i told you, i took an existing makefile that i edited, i will try this and let you know

Thanks again

Comment: Actually im gonna be busy this afternoon, so i'll try this tomorrow :)
Thanks again for your kind help!

Comment: So here is the new makefile http://pastebin.com/u4pJKJKt
Here is the make output : http://pastebin.com/NzsFetrn
The undefined references are gblobal extern variables i declare in approx.h, and that i set in approx.c (and that i'll have to use in producteur.c)

Comment: @Moons, where is `indice_prod` defined? And edit your original question ideally. (And remove the LINKOBJ variable, you don't need it)

Comment: @Moons, show how indice_prod et al. are defined. They're clearly not in `approx.o`

Comment: Here is approx.c : http://pastebin.com/TZw5jHWj
Here is approx.h : http://pastebin.com/qjbRvH03

(i can't post them into the main post, my reputation isn't high enough :) )

Comment: When i set a value for indice_prod in approx.h, then i get the following error : multiple definition of indice_prod !
That's weird!

Comment: @Moon, the problem is you haven't reserved any space for those variables. You must define the variable somewhere (*not* in a header though!). E.g. in approx.c, write `int indice_prod;` and the same for others. (Assuming you really want those variables to be global).

Never define variables in a header. Extern is OK (since it doesn't define them). I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, it is compiling.
So now that i have added the lines in the .c, I can use them in every other .c ??
I didn't knew i had towrite these 3 lines, thaught when I included the .h, it'd do the job!
Well i'm happy i'm able to work again on that school work, thank you.

Comment: @Moon, Yes, you can use them in other C files.